# How to split string into only two parts with a given separator in Swift?

Tags: swift, string, split

I have a requirement to split a string into 2 parts based on the first separator, for example the following source data:

```
1,Froederick,Frankenstien
2,Ludwig,Van,Beethoven
3,Anne Frank
```

Above each array element to be separated as following:

```
1st Component    2nd Component
1                Froederick,Frankenstien
2                Ludwig,Van,Beethoven
3                Anne Frank
```

I'm familiar with `String.components(separatedBy: String)` but I'm not sure how to only split once, as I get 3 components for 1st string, 4 components for 2nd string. Is there a Swifty (elegant) way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `split` on a `characters` property of a string and set the `maxSplits` parameter to 1. For example:

```
let splitString = "1,Froederick,Frankenstien".characters.split(separator: ",", maxSplits: 1)
```

The result is an array of `CharacterView` that need to be converted into strings for example using `map` along with `init(_ characters:)` initializer of a String.

```
let strings = splitString.map { String($0) }
```

This should produce an array `["1", "Froederick,Frankenstien"]`.